# Get ID of selected contenteditable element's child where cursor caret is located

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

I'm currently trying to make an editor using contenteditable divs, but I'm  having an issue where clicking backspace in say **child-2** at the start will result in merging **child-1** and **child-2** together, which defeats its own purpose.

I'm finding the current caret position using the function:

```
caret: function() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt) return sel.getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Which has been working perfectly, but to fix the merging issue I need to find out which element is currently selected and use that data with the caret location to use `event.preventDefault()` and stop a potential merge.

This is frame that I'm using and talking about:

```
<div id="parent" contenteditable="true">
  <div id="child-1">
    One
  </div>
  <div id="child-2">
    Two
  </div>
  <div id="child-3">
    Three
  </div>
</div>
```

To find the selected element I've tried this:

```
console.log(document.activeElement);
```

To see if this prints out the **ID of the child** selected, though this outputs the entire parent element into the console instead of just the ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm) to easily find the clicked node. Other events such as key and mouse can be added as well.

**Details are commented in demo**

### Demo

```js
// Refernce the parent of all of the target nodes
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
// Register the click event to #parent
parent.addEventListener('click', idNode);

// This is the callback that is invoked on each click
function idNode(e) {
  /* If the node clicked (e.target) is not the 
  || the registered event listener 
  || (e.currentTarget = #parent)
  */
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    // Get the #id of clicked node
    var ID = e.target.id;
    // Reference e.target by its #id
    var child = document.getElementById(ID);

  }
  // Log the #id of each e.target at every click
  console.log('The caret is located at ' + ID);
  
  // Return the e.target as a DOM node when needed
  return child;

}
```

```html
<div id="parent" contenteditable="true">
  <div id="child-1">
    One
  </div>
  <div id="child-2">
    Two
  </div>
  <div id="child-3">
    Three
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My knight in shining armor.

Comment: You are very welcome. BTW you can add key and mouse events as well.

Comment: @zer00ne hey, i tried adding key events but when i'm applying 'keydown' i got parent ID back.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `tabindex="0"` to the child elements, which makes them focusable, which will select the children when using `document.activeElement` (otherwise it's always the parent which has the focus):

```js
console.log(document.activeElement);
```

```html
<div id="parent" contenteditable="true">
  <div id="child-1" tabindex="0">
    One
  </div>
  <div id="child-2" tabindex="0">
    Two
  </div>
  <div id="child-3" tabindex="0">
    Three
  </div>
</div>
```

After comment: I am adding a screenshot of this very snippet: I clicked into the word "Two": You can see the dotted border around that line indicating the focus status:

[image]

Comment: In order to focus on the element, I have to double click at the end of the content, which is a bit of a hassle for a user.

Comment: no - if you just click into it (i.e. place the cursor), the element is focused (usually indicated by a thin dotted border around it)

Comment: When clicking on one of the three child divs, it just focuses on the parent? https://gyazo.com/3908eeadaad411036bb119c87114e4a8

Comment: that link opens a blank page here (grey background is all there is)

Comment: please see what I added to my answer

Comment: I've looked at it then ran the snippet myself and it's not the same, using Google Chrome?

Comment: Firefox Mac.... Your link works in Google Chrome, but maybe that also has to do with privacy/cookie settings...

Comment: Potentially Johannes :P Thanks for your answer, by the way, I appreciated the quickness to it

Answer (score 0):

By using `document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id` you can get the id of the parent element of the caret.

**Example**

```js
function getParentId() {
    var caret = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var caretParent = caret.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode;
    console.log(caretParent.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" contenteditable="true">
  <div id="child-1" tabindex="0">
    One
  </div>
  <div id="child-2" tabindex="0">
    Two
  </div>
  <div id="child-3" tabindex="0">
    Three
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="getParentId()">Get Id</button>
```